# Using S3 for uploads but not allowing public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My idea was (is) to create an S3 bucket for allowing users to upload binary objects.  The next step would be to confirm the upload and the API will then initiate processing of the file.

To make it more secure the client would first request an upload location.  The API then allocates and pre-creates a one-time use directory on S3 for this upload, and sets access policy on that directory to allow a file to be dumped in there (but ideally not be read or even overwritten).

After confirmation by the client the API initiates processing and clean-up.

The problem I'm facing is authentication and authorisation.  Simplest would be to allow public write with difficult-to-guess bucket directories, eg

s3://bucket/year/month/day/UUID/UUID/filename

Where the date is added in to allow clean-up later for orphaned files (and should volume grow to require it one can add hours/minutes.

The first UUID is not meaningful other than providing a unique upload location.  The second identifies the user.

The entire path is created by the API.  The API then allows the user access to write into that final directory.  (The user should not be allowed to create this directory).

The question I'm stuck with is that from googling it seems that public writable S3 buckets is considered bad practice, even horribly so.

What alternative do I have?
a) provide the client with some kind of access token?
b) create an IAM account for every uploader (I do not want to be tied to Amazon this way)
c) Any other options?

P.S And is it possible to control the actual file name that the client can use to create a file from the policy?

Comment: If you route all client requests (upload/download/list/...) through your application, then your application is the only one that needs access to S3 via a unique IAM role.  No need to give access to your users - you just have to authenticate/authorize users as usual, then serve their requests using the appropriate bucket prefix.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid uploads going via the API since it doesn't scale.

Comment: You could implement a serverless API using lambda that would scale.

Comment: I have just chanced upon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html and in there specifically the section on Authenticating Post Requests.  Some of the terminology is new so I'm busy going down that rabbit hole now.

Comment: How are the users uploading files? Is it via a web browser, mobile app, or something else? How are your users authenticated?

Comment: Users are authenticated in the app (During login the API issues a token).

The existing clients are native mobile and web based.  All of these will need to be updated to use the S3 buckets once that is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, your goals are to:

- Securely allow users to **upload specific files** to an S3 bucket
- **Limit access** by preventing users from reading or writing other files
- Ideally, upload the files **directly to S3** without going through your server

You can do this by generating [presigned PUT URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) server-side and returning those URLs to the client. The client can use those URLs to upload directly to S3. The client is limited to only the filename you specify when signing the URL. It will be limited to PUT only. You keep your AWS access keys secure on the server and never send it to the client.

If you are using the PutObject API, you only need to sign one URL per file. If you are using the multi-part upload API, it's a bit more complicated and you'll need to start and finish the upload server-side and send presigned UploadPart URLs to the client.

Comment: This solution matches closely what I need.  I will try to implement this asap.