# AWS Transfer service - SFTP - deny ability to list directory is affecting ability to put file to the directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to set up permissions for a user account on AWS Transfer Service with SFTP protocol. I have a use case where a user should be able to add a file to a directory but not list the files in it.

When I tweak the IAM role to deny 's3:ListBucket' for a specific subdirectory the put operation fails as well. Theoretically s3 does allow to Put object without having the ability to list the prefixes. AWS transfer service however seems to be implicitly using the list bucket operation before put. Has anyone managed to deny listing ability while still being able to upload.

IAM policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>"
            ],
            "Sid": "AllowListDirectories",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "data/partner_2/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyMkdir",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*/"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyListFilesInSubDirectory",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "data/partner_2/data/incoming/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "AllowReadWirteInSubDirectory",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/data/partner_2/data/incoming/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "AllowOnlyReadInADifferentDirectory",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/data/partner_2/data/outgoing/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The output from SFTP client:

```
sftp> cd data/incoming
sftp> ls
Couldn't read directory: Permission denied
sftp> put /Users/foo/Downloads/test.log
Uploading /Users/foo/Downloads/test.log to /data/incoming/test.log
remote open("/data/incoming/test.log"): Permission denied
sftp> get test-one.txt
Fetching /data/incoming/test-one.txt to test-one.txt
sftp> exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have to allow the upload to your s3 bucket through SFTP, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190717/3145960) doesn't quite meet your requirements. If the SFTP requirement wasn't there, you may be able to provide [pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to the client to upload files securely.

I couldn't manage to find an exact solution, however, a workaround could be allowing list+upload permission to a directory in your bucket that is specific to the client/user. Got a [helpful video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_HHSnoFsoM) to share, and corresponding [medium article](https://enrico-portolan.medium.com/easy-sftp-setup-with-aws-transfer-family-2f9b5782d435).

Basically, the IAM policy the user is attached to will have the following permissions to a specific folder while you block all public access to your bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2023-02-16",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": [
            "restricted-folder-user-1/*",
            "restricted-folder-user-1"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<arn of restricted-folder-user-1>*"
    }
  ]
}
```